# horizontal scroll view not scrolling properly in recyclerview

Tags: android-layout

Hi i have to implement recycler view inside horizontal scroll view..i have to use both horizontal scrollview scrolling and recycler view item vertical scrolling.conflict between recycler view and horizontal scroll view

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/header_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background">

    </View>
      //customn scroll view
    <com.app.Constants.CustomHorizontalScrollView

        android:id="@+id/layer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hView"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </com.app.Constants.CustomHorizontalScrollView>
```

And i have dynamically insert the recycler view into it , this is my requirement

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="360dp"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView


        android:id="@+id/recycleview_list"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I try this code but not able to scroll horizontally

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("innnn","func");
                rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);


                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: can any one help on this..i have struck with that